# How to Use a Browsed File in Allegro 5?

Tags: c, file, allegro5

I need to create a very simple program that will let the user browse an image, which will then be used for a bitmap that will be displayed in the screen.

I know how to create a simple native file dialog with Allegro 5, but I don't know how to use the selected file for my bitmap.

This is my code:

```
ALLEGRO_FILECHOOSER *filechooser;
    filechooser = al_create_native_file_dialog("C:", "Choose a file.", "*.*;*.jpg;", 1);
    al_show_native_file_dialog(display, filechooser);
```

When I click on the files, the native file dialog disappears and nothing happens at all. I searched a lot for this matter, but I could not find an answer to my problem.

How do I create a bitmap with the selected image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start by looking at what the [API](http://liballeg.org/a5docs/trunk/native_dialog.html) defines:

- `ALLEGRO_FILECHOOSER`: the handle to the file dialog box.
- `al_show_native_file_dialog`: the method to display the dialog associated with the handle.

So, after you create the dialog, initialize and display it, the user will select a file. However, this dialog supports the selection of multiple files at a time, thats what the **`size_t i`** in **`al_get_native_file_dialog_path`** is for.

In order for you to know how many files the user selected you must then call `al_get_native_file_dialog_count` and store the value it returned somewhere.

Later on, you will now call `al_get_native_file_dialog_path` inside the al_load_bitmap function with the number of the file you would like to open and *voila!* You have the image the user requested, or the images if that the case, but implementing that is a good exercise to do a slideshow app.

Now an example:

```
ALLEGRO_FILECHOOSER *filechooser;
filechooser = al_create_native_file_dialog("C:", "Choose a file.", "*.*;*.jpg;", 1);
al_show_native_file_dialog(display, filechooser);

/* Actually I will not use this but leaving it here as example only*/
int counter = al_get_native_file_dialog_count(filechooser);

/* Instead of cycling counter, I will select 1 to refer to the first image selected*/
const char* path = al_get_native_file_dialog_path(filechooser, 1);
ALLEGRO_BITMAP *image = al_load_bitmap(path);
```

After this, you display the image stored on that `ALLEGRO_BITMAP` to the screen.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment! Unfortunately I am very confused, and the API is not really helping me :/
What exactly is **i**'s objective in this function?
Also, could you please explain what is **mode** in _al_create_native_file_dialog_?
Thanks a lot for your help, but Allegro's GUI is still strange for me, and I can't find the answer for my problem anywhere :c

Comment: No problem with that @Pedro , however right now on my time zone it is 23:10 (11:10pm) and its time to sleep :) Tomorrow I edit the question. To better explain this, but i represents one of the files in case the user selected multiple files at the same time in the dialog. Around 7pm tomorrow I have time to edit this so heads up!

Comment: Thanks! I'll be waiting :v

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understand everything, and the program is working perfectly! I thought no one would ever answer my question :)
By the way, how do you know so much about allegro? :O

Comment: @PedroHenrique well to be honest, I learned how to use this function of Allegro by trying to make an answer for it... I've been working with the library for many years but at a slow pace, however, by making lots of side projects I've managed to get the hang of the flow of it. Just keep coding as practice makes the master. The API documentation they have sometimes leaves things unclear such as this example, but try reading it and understanding how it connects with everything else. Glad it helped.